# npx fusion verify & npx fusion zip

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, npx, fusion

I spent a few days scratching my head about what this issue could be. I figured it out and wanted to post the solution on the internet since there wasn't any luck on google when I was searching.

When trying to run npx fusion verify or npx fusion zip, I was getting the below error.

Warning: No resource found to remove for project "fusion_.verify".
"fusion_.verify" is not a valid project name: it must contain only characters from [a-z0-9_-] and start with [a-z0-9]
Warning: No resource found to remove for project "fusion_.verify".

The solution was to update fusion cli by running:

npm install --save-dev @arc-fusion/cli@latest

best of luck to all. Sorry it's not a question but it will help someone someday